# Does the docker version of opennms have Rest API?

Tags: docker, rest, opennms

I am building a frontend-like for OpenNMS and chose to install OpenNMS in a docker container. I need to use the Rest API to further my project and when I try to send a request to
`http://localhost:8980/opennms/rest`, using the python requests library the return code is `404`.
Does OpenNMS for docker not have Rest API or do I need to install it on my core system instead of docker.

P.S. This is my first time trying to do use the Rest API of an application.
imgur link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0odL.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are calling is just the base URL for our rest resources. For Nodes as an example, you can test this with `curl -u admin http://localhost:8980/opennms/rest/nodes`. The REST API endpoints are described in the documentation here

Comment: Thanks. But you might have forgotten to link the documentation website :P